# Saving changes with a complex type and model first

Tags: entity-framework, complextype

I am using stored procedures (by mandate) and I am using a complex type/function import to retrieve data.  My question is how do you handle updating the data that is based on a complex type in model first?  Is there a way to attach an update stored procedure to it? I don't see a way to bring these entities in the designer to use the tool to add a sp to it like you would an entity. If not, What is the best practice around this?

Comment: Do you really know what a complex type it? If so, how is it possible to attach an SP to a set of sevearl roperties that can exist in different tables? Please, learn what a complex type is!

Comment: In entity framework you can update an entity by way of a stored procedure, it would be nice if you can update a entity that is basically a complex type in the same manner.  By the way entity framework updates properties from multiple tables.

Comment: And by the way there really is no reason to be rude.

Comment: A complex type behaves as a "pack of properties without identity". This "pack of properties" can exists in several different entities (= db tables), and even there can be several instances of the same complex type in the same EF entity (= db table). So, can you explain what you mean by "attach an stored procedure to it (it = a complex type)"? You must understand that your question makes not sense at all, at least as it's stated. Please, add a code sample or reword your question in a way that makes sense.

Comment: BTW, apologies for my rudeness, but it's just a way to call your attention so that you ask yourself what can be so wrong to get such a comment. If I take the time to make a comment is to let you know that soemthing is wrong with ypur question. And, of course, if you make it more clear, and I can help you, I'll help you.